# Is there a GUI based editor for master boot records (MBR)

Tags: linux, hardware, firmware

Is there a GUI based editor (or educational software, or informative webpage - I don' really want to *edit* anything here) that can create a hexdump of a master boot record, and then label (like a map) all the items that it has found?

Here's a dump of one of my hard drives, I'd like to know what everything means

```
○ → sudo dd if=/dev/sdc count=1 | hexdump -C

00000000  fa b8 00 10 8e d0 bc 00  b0 b8 00 00 8e d8 8e c0  |...............|
00000010  fb be 00 7c bf 00 06 b9  00 02 f3 a4 ea 21 06 00  |...|.........!..|
00000020  00 be be 07 38 04 75 0b  83 c6 10 81 fe fe 07 75  |....8.u........u|
00000030  f3 eb 16 b4 02 b0 01 bb  00 7c b2 80 8a 74 01 8b  |.........|...t..|
00000040  4c 02 cd 13 ea 00 7c 00  00 eb fe 00 00 00 00 00  |L.....|.........|
00000050  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  38 43 0a 00 00 00 00 20  |........8C..... |
000001c0  21 00 83 fe ff ff 00 08  00 00 00 80 e0 e8 00 00  |!...............|
000001d0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200
```

I can get the info for the disk identifier:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc | grep ident

Disk identifier: 0x000a4338
```

and the string `0a4338` is right there in the hexdump, in litte-endian representation (`38 43 0a 00`), on the 4th or 5th row from below.

But I don't know how to what the other fields and bytes mean.

I know `sudo parted -l` gives me a lot of info

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA DT01ACA2 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  primary  ext4
```

but this can come from elsewhere (from the drive's firmware maybe?)

**Update**: I want something similar as the screenshot in this [Answer on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/1115972/viewing-contents-of-hard-drive-in-binary/1116687#1116687)

Comment: The screenshot is just another hex editor... like your hexdump output with colour

Comment: I want a hex editor with built-in, rich documentation-features for MBRs and GPTs (e.g. cool visualisations such as Tooltips)